# JxBrowser comvert html to pdf with 7.X release

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, html2pdf, jxbrowser

I want to convert an html file to pdf using TeamDev jxbrowser. I want to trigger it automatically wihout any extra print dialog or popup etc just by executing some code. And I also want to set some extra settings. In the 6.X versions I can see more detailed options by coding

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013120-print-settings

```
browser.setPrintHandler(new PrintHandler() {
            @Override
            public PrintStatus onPrint(PrintJob printJob) {
                PrintSettings printSettings = printJob.getPrintSettings();
                printSettings.setLandscape(true);
```

But in 7.x relases there are very few details for customizing pdf generation step by code.

https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/printing.html#print-preview

- Is it not possible with newer releases getting a **PrintSettings**
  instance?
- Can we set custom header and footer content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Printing API that allows programmatically printing the currently loaded web page using the PDF printer is not available in JxBrowser 7. It's already on our [roadmap](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/roadmap/). We do our best to introduce this functionality in one of the next versions.

I recommend that you follow us on https://twitter.com/JxBrowserTeam to be notified when this functionality is released.

**UPD**: In JxBrowser 7.13 the Printing API has been extended with functionality that allows programmatically configure print settings and print a web page without displaying the Print Preview dialog. The API allows you to save the currently loaded web page as a PDF document. Read more at https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/printing.html#configuring-settings

The following example demonstrates how to save a web page as PDF:

```
import static com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.RenderingMode.OFF_SCREEN;
import static com.teamdev.jxbrowser.print.Orientation.PORTRAIT;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.browser.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.browser.callback.PrintCallback;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.browser.callback.PrintHtmlCallback;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.frame.Frame;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.print.PdfPrinter;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.print.PdfPrinter.HtmlSettings;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.print.PrintJob;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.print.event.PrintCompleted;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * This example demonstrates how to configure print settings programmatically and print the
 * currently loaded web page using the built-in PDF printer. In general, it shows how to save the
 * currently loaded web page as a PDF document.
 */
public final class PrintToPdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(OFF_SCREEN);
        Browser browser = engine.newBrowser();
        browser.set(PrintCallback.class, (params, tell) -> tell.print());
        browser.set(PrintHtmlCallback.class, (params, tell) -> {
            PdfPrinter<PdfPrinter.HtmlSettings> pdfPrinter =
                    params.printers().pdfPrinter();
            PrintJob<HtmlSettings> printJob = pdfPrinter.printJob();
            printJob.settings()
                    .pdfFilePath(Paths.get("google.pdf").toAbsolutePath())
                    .enablePrintingBackgrounds()
                    .orientation(PORTRAIT)
                    .apply();
            printJob.on(PrintCompleted.class, event -> {
                if (event.isSuccess()) {
                    System.out.println("Printing is completed successfully.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Printing has failed.");
                }
            });
            tell.proceed(pdfPrinter);
        });
        browser.navigation().loadUrlAndWait("https://google.com");
        browser.mainFrame().ifPresent(Frame::print);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope we will be able to set custom footer and header content?

Comment: From our initial research, unfortunately, Chromium doesn't provide API that allows modifying header/footer text when printing a web page (

Comment: @benchpresser in 7.20 we extended the API to let you print using customer header and footer. See the release notes at https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/release-notes/2021/v7-20.html#header-and-footer